# Get Customer ID in Home Page - Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I need to get the Customer ID primary in Home Page, but not have a Session Interface to give this information.

I tried theses:

```
\Magento\Backend\Model\Session
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session
\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Session
```

Exists one interface to give Customer ID on **every page**?

Answer (score 0):

There are methods available in magento2 to get customer id, one of the method is using Object Manager as below code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');  
$customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); // get the customer Id
```

Answer (score 0):

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Form extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

```
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {

        var_dump($this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId());
        exit();
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```